# Error when code signing .framework

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoapods, xcodebuild, rncryptor

I have used CocoaPods to install the [RNCryptor](https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor) framework. Which has worked perfectly on my application, and when archiving the application manually through xcode works perfectly.

But when I try archive using terminal with the command:

```
xcodebuild -workspace "$APP.xcworkspace" -scheme "$APP" archive
```

I get the error:

```
/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign ... /RNCryptor.framework

no identity found
Command /bin/sh failed with exit code 1
```

Comment: Having the same issue, any updates?

Comment: I think I gave up haha. Sorry man!

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you need to set the codesigning identity in your project which incorporates Pods.

Go to your project settings and look in the Code Signing section and see if it's set with a name like "`iPhone Distribution: Maximillian`" or "`iPhone Development: Maximillian`".

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the issue was not related to the framework. The updated version of the provisioning profile required a different signing identity; when I installed the new certificate, the issue was resolved.